# CParseError reading csv file in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Getting a CParcerError:Error -tokenizing data, expected 4 fields in line 6, saw 5- when reading the following csv file with pandas

```
1   0.707   2881292.08  992607.12   57.46   57.46   *BB 2.9028
2   1.043   1187965.81  496643.82   23.69   23.69   *BB 2.392
3   1.685   477470.92   142957.85   9.52    9.52    *BB 3.3399
4   2.755   201900.68   36276.04    4.03    4.03    *BB 5.5657
5   3.196   206744.22   31258.27    4.12    4.12    *BB 6.6141
6   5.953   29364.36    2362.28     0.59    0.59    *BB 12.4305


def csv_new(folder):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
        data = pd.read_csv(infilename, sep = ',', index = None)
        new_filename = ".....fid/new.csv" %(filename)
        data.to_csv(new_filename)

csv_new('....fid/')
```

I've been debugging this for a long time and still have had no success. I see no problem with the data and its structure. I'm not sure why I'm getting a CParseError?

conversion from txt file to csv:

```
def txt_to_csv(folder):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
        data = pd.read_csv(infilename, sep ='/t', header = None, skiprows = 2, index_col = 0, engine = 'python')
        new_data = data[24:30]
        new_filename = "........fid/%s.csv" %(filename)
        new_data.to_csv(new_filename, sep = '"', header = None)
```

Comment: Is that your real csv? because I don't see commas, I see white space, remove `sep=','` and use `delim_whitespace=True` in `read_csv`

Comment: It is my real csv. In short, I converted a bunch of text files to csv files and now I am trying to add column names to these csv's so that I can select specific columns to export to a summary csv.

Comment: I've added this function to the description